# Hbase access error

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hortonworks-data-platform

When I try to grant access to a user in hbase I get the following error:

```
 grant 'root', 'RWXCA'

   ERROR: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.coprocessor.CoprocessorException: java.net.ConnectException:    Connection refused
           at    com.xasecure.authorization.hbase.XaSecureAuthorizationCoprocessor.grant(XaSecureAuthorizationCoproces sor.java:1040)
           at   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.AccessControlProtos$AccessControlService$1.grant(AccessControlProtos.java:9933)
           at    org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.AccessControlProtos$AccessControlService.callMethod(Access   ControlProtos.java:10097)
           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.execService(HRegion.java:6725)
           at    org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.execServiceOnRegion(HRegionServer.java:3415)
           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.execService(HRegionServer.java:3397)
           at    org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientProtos.java:29998)
           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:2078)
           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:108)
           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor.consumerLoop(RpcExecutor.java:114)
           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$1.run(RpcExecutor.java:94)
           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Running `HDP2.2 sandbox`.

> hbase.coprocessor.region.classes=com.xasecure.authorization.hbase.XaSecureAuthorizationCoprocessor
>
> hbase.coprocessor.master.classes=com.xasecure.authorization.hbase.XaSecureAuthorizationCoprocessor

Any ideas?
Cheers,
Colman

Answer (score 0):

Knowing this was an old thread, but FWIW, I am assuming you don't have XASecure installed on the sandbox which stores and handles role-based authorization. That is why you saw XaSecureAuthorizationCoprocessor failed to connect. AFAIK, XASecure (the company) was acquired by Hortonworks.

Another workaround may be to write your own authorization module, package, drop it to HBase path and change the HBase settings to point to it.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but on a HDP 3.1.5 cluster, when executing an hbase grant command, this error can be shown when Ranger is down.

If this is your case, you just have to start Ranger up to avoid this error.